# Page doesn't move when android softinput popup again

Tags: android

I have a page with some `EditText`s. When they get focus, the soft keyboard will appear and the whole page will move up to let user see the input area. But, when I click the back button to hide the keyboard and click the `EditText` again, the page will stay and the keyboard will blank the input box. When click other and click this `EditText` again, the page will move up. I have another page worked fine.

The two pages are in the same activity. The activity has a `FrameLayout`. The two pages are extended from Fragment.

In `Manifest.xml`:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".XXXActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

In `Activity.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
<!-- 
other things... 
 -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/IDXXXPage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

`EditText` in two fragments are the same:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

<!-- 
other things... 
all edit text are the same
 -->
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/IDXXXX"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="text"
            />
```

Has anyone met this problem before? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

Comment: I'd like to keep the size of the EditText. It makes it smaller.

Answer (score 0):

It only happens when the keyboard is hidden.
When it loses the focus, everything is working fine, so I solved by creating a class extended from EditText, clear the focus when the keyboard is hidden.

```java
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK &&
                event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            clearFocus();
        }
        return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
    }
```

But I still don't know why and how it happens.